# Is the subnet combination correct?

Tags: subnet

Given the bellow networks, I'm asked if 172.16.0.0/13 is a correct supernet of the nets .16, .17, .18, .19, .20 and .21.

I would say that since every net has a /16 mask (making them all have 2^16 = 65536 adresses), in total I need 6 * 65356 adresses.
So with 2^19 = 524288, I know that I need 19 Bits in the Host part or equivalently, need 32-19=13 bits in the network part. Therefore the net 172.16.0.0/13 should be a valid super net. Am I right?

[image]

Comment: Yes, 172.16.0.0/13 address range includes all addresses within 172.(16-21).0.0/16 address ranges. But this net scheme is, of course, wrong.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the reply. Please help, what is wrong with the scheme?

Comment: The node S0/0/1 must act as a bridge - but I can not find the goal acieved and the task solved by. And broadcast addresses differs.

Comment: Why would it need to act as a bridge? This is basic CIDR routing.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion is right (172.16./13 *is* a supernet of all six networks), but the methodology is not reliable.

Having a shorter prefix (13 < 16) is of course a requirement for a "super net" but it's not the only requirement. For example, 172.16.0.0/14 *wouldn't* be a supernet for 172.20.0.0/16. As another example, 172.20.0.0/13 wouldn't be a valid network number *at all*.

The real requirement has nothing to do with number of total addresses; it's about bitwise match. If the network is a /13, then the *first 13 bits* of its address must match the subnet addresses. In your case, that's the whole first number (`127`) and 5 bits of the second number (`16`, `20`, etc.)

```
                       ┌──────┐ ┌───────┐
Supernet:    172.16    10101100 00010 000


Match:       172.16    10101100 00010 000
                          ...
             172.19    10101100 00010 011
             172.20    10101100 00010 100
                          ...
             172.23    10101100 00010 111


No match:    172.24    10101100 00011 000
```

This would also tell you whether a network is valid in the first place. For example, 172.20.0.0/13 wouldn't be valid, because it has some '1' bits in the remaining "host" part.